# Combining audio files

Tags: java, android, audio

I recorded some audio files, stored them in sdcard. I need to combine all the recorded files into a single audiofile. I used the following code. My problem is the combined file contains only the first recorded file. Any suggestions...In readAudioAsStream() method i tried to combine the files.

```
public void readAudioAsStream() {
    getFullAudioPath()

    File f;
    FileInputStream ins = null;

    try 
    {
        String comfile=getCombineFile();
        //FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(comfile);
        Log.d("combined file",comfile);
        File file=new File(comfile);
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        Log.d("path size",Integer.toString(audFullPath.size()));
        for (int i=0;i<audFullPath.size();i++)
        {   
            String filepath=audFullPath.get(i);
            Log.d("Filepath",filepath);
            f=new File(audFullPath.get(i));
            fileContent = new byte[(int)f.length()];
            ins=new FileInputStream(audFullPath.get(i));
            int numofbytes=ins.read(fileContent);
            System.out.println("Number Of Bytes Read===========>>>"+numofbytes);
            raf.seek(file.length());
            raf.write(fileContent);
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
}
public ArrayList<String> getFullAudioPath() {
    ArrayList<String> fullPath=new ArrayList<String>();
    fullPath.clear();

    String path=filePath();
    File f=new File(path);
    if(f.isDirectory())
    {
        File[] files=f.listFiles();
        for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
        {
            String fpath=path+File.separator+files[i].getName().toString().trim();
            System.out.println("File Full Path======>>>"+fpath);
            fullPath.add(fpath);
        }
    }       
    return fullPath;
}
public String filePath() {
    String newFolderName="/MyAudio";
    String extstoredir=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    String newPath=extstoredir+newFolderName;
    return newPath;
}

public String getCombineFile() {
    String newFolderName="/MyComAudio";
    String extstoredir=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    String path=extstoredir+newFolderName;
    File myNewPath=new File(path);
    if(!myNewPath.exists()) {
        myNewPath.mkdir();
    }
    String audname="ComAudio";
    String ext=".3gp";
    File audio=new File(myNewPath,audname+ext);             

    if(audio.exists()) {
        audio.delete();
    }
    String audpath=path+"/"+audname+ext;
    Log.d("Combined audio file",audpath);
    return audpath;
}
```

Comment: What is format of your audio files?

Comment: I am recording 3gp files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't merge two `.3gp` files just by writing content of one `.3gp` file at the end of another `.3gp` file.

Comment: You can record audio to files using `AudioRecorder`. This will give you audio files in raw PCM format. You can merge them together. But resulting file is not going to be playable. You'll need to add correct `WAV` header at the beginning of that file to make it playable. Note that `AudioRecorder` is harder to use then `MediaRecorder`.

Comment: I couldn't found anything about AudioRecorder in developers site. could u pls suggest me any useful link or any sample coding.

Comment: AudioRecord doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html; You'll need to look for tutorials yourself.

Comment: i have record audio in android by using the following site http://matrix-examplecode.blogspot.in/2011/12/audio-recording-part-2.html. in the above example site they convert raw file as wav file format. my need is convert raw file as mp3 file format. how to do it. please help me.